# Program user's credentials to automatically login to websites

Tags: security, web, authentication

Here's my scenario - I have the credentials for a couple of websites that need username and password to login.  I would like to programmatically do this but just don't where to strrt.

For example, say the website is www.mywebsite.com and the the U: UserID and P: admin.

I am thinking something like this (this is of course pseudo-code): open("www.mywebsite?username=UserID,password=admin".

Can someone lead me down a path where I could learn more on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: From a security perspective, this seems like a bad idea...  Why not just use one of the many free password managers out there?  Or possibly a Single Sign On solution? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on

Comment: These sites are public facing sites.  I do not own them.  I just don't want to, when the page loads, to be on the login page, i.e. I want to go to the logged-on page already.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is note a solution, but when I need to analyze a site I plan to scrape data off that requires a login, I usually use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to record my session.  It will show you all the data between your browser and the site, so you can build the exact URL and variables needed to login to protected sites.

Comment: THanks Zachary - see, this is the stuff that I was looking for.  Since I have never done this before, I was not sure what this concept was called.  Now I will research website 'scraping'.  Any other ideas will be appreciated.